# How can i get an image inside an li to disregard padding with css

Tags: css

How can i get an image inside an li to disregard padding with css?

Using a jquery selectable with following css:

```
.selectable li {margin: 1px;padding: 0.4em;height: 0.52em;line-height: 0.54em;}
```

Is it possible to have an image inside an `li` with the above css without getting effected by the padding? That is I want the image to start right at the top border of the `li`, but I want other content to be padded still.

Comment: Can you please show some more CSS, HTML or even setup a http://jsbin.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a

```
position:relative;
```

to your li, and then declare absolute positioning for your image.

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

Only disadvantage with this is you'll need to declare a min-height for your li, the same or greater than the image heights. If they're all the same size it's fine, otherwise not so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to add another class to your HTML, then I think this solution could work for you. Add another class removing the padding, set the li height to be the same as the image and set vertical align to top.

[See here](http://codepen.io/cneering/pen/KBCuh)

```
<!-- HTML -->
<ul>
<li>Item One</li>
<li class="cat"><img src="cat.jpg"></li>
<li>Item Three</li>
<li>Item Four</li>
</ul>

* CSS */
li {
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  height: 0.52em;
  line-height: 0.54em;}

.cat img{
  width:100px; 
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;} 

li.cat {
   height: 100px;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;}
```

Comment: What if one day codepen closes it's services? please add the relevant code in your answer.